# Erro de verificação login PHP

Tags: php, aplicação-web

Pessoal estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação PHP para um acampamento de minha Igreja, aí eu preciso verificar se o usuário está logado para poder redireciona-lo caso ele esteja logado e tente recarregar a pagina de login e solicitar o acesso, caso não esteja logado, basicamente eu quero redirecionar quem tiver logado para que ele nao digite usuario e senha de novo e, caso nao esteja logado, exibir a pagina de login normalmente. Aí é que tá o problema. Eu fiz um arquivo para as funções que vou precisar e o arquivo de login, os caminhos dos arquivos estão corretos, mas tá dando esse erro aqui quando acesso o `login.php`:

> Notice : Undefined index: logged_in in
>   /home/vol15_6/epizy.com/epiz_22599397/htdocs/aplicacao/controller/functions.php
>   on line 16

Na linhas 14 - 21 do arquivo `functions.php` eu tenho isso aqui:

```
function isLoggedIn()
{
  if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) || $_SESSION['logged_in'] == true)
  {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

No meu arquivo `login.php` eu tenho essa chamada aqui:

```
<?php
if (isLoggedIn()) {
  // Redireciona para dashboard
  header("Location: /dashboard");
} else {
  // Num faz nada
}
?>
<html>(muito html e css)</html>
```

O que está ocasionando o erro e como eu posso corrigir? Se alguém souber ficarei muito grato.

Comment: ele não está encontrando o, $_session, pode ser que ela ñ foi iniciada, caso foi, verifique se você atribuiu um valor $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;

Comment: No meu caso a variável é inicializada com `session_start()` e eu apenas atribuo `true` para `['logged_in']` quando o login é efetuado, todavia, no meu metodo de verificação, q vê se o usuário está logado, eu verifico se a variável está setada ou se é `true`. Não sei mais o que fazer.

Comment: coloque um comentário no if /* if ate o final dele */ e coloque um print_r($_SESSION) no lugar, e observe se foi setado corretamente quando tiver o login, pois o erro está acusando que não existe a variável , e segundo sua condição seria mais correto colocar && no lugar de || "&&" = a AND, e "||" = a OR, então axo que o mais correto seria SE (Se existe a variavel) é ela estiver verdadeira, então responde verdade ou então falsa

Comment: e para setar precisar ser $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;

Comment: Quando efetuo o login, realmente o valor é atribuido corretamente e eu corrigi a minha função conforme vc indicou. Depois da correção e de verificar se estava sendo corretamente atribuido o valor, tirei os comentarios do if e quando faço login e tento acessar a pagina de login (que deveria verificar o login e redirecionar para /dashboard) eu sou redirecionado para um erro 404. Ou seja, se estiver logado a pagina de login deixa de funcionar e retorna um 404 ao inves de redirecionar, mas se n estiver logado a pagina de login funciona normal (exceto a verificação).

Comment: então comenta o header e coloca um echo "estou logado"; caso funcione e o location do header que está errado... mais ao meu ver ele já errado pois vc não pegou o id de qual caminho nativo está

Comment: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header.php da uma olhada na 6ª nota, tem varios jeito de se axar ela.. ou pd setar mais simples com http://site/dashboard

Comment: $_SERVER e mais automático, você não terá problema quando publicar seu sistema caso seja local, você terá que lembrar de modificá-lo corretamente quando publicar no servidor

Comment: Lembrando que você tem que iniciar nos dois arquivos... Exemplo você inicia quando o cara faz o login em uma página chamada login.php, porém depois quando ele for redirecionado para a outra página por exemplo is_logged.php você tem que iniciar a sessão novamente, a menos que você esteja fazendo um include de algum arquivo que sempre inicializa a sessão

Comment: Solucionei usando JS. Quando chegar em casa mando a solução, mas obrigado a todos.